# Is there any gem to send request to some service in xml format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, web-services, rest, xml-serialization

I want to send request to some third party service in xml and also expecting response in xml. I'm searching for some gem or any idea how to do this.

Thing which is in my mind is to

1. make some partail _example.xml.builder
2. onclick from my view to some button send ajax request to controller action and use render_to_string to render that xml doc and then
3. Save it in some variable
4. and then call to that service method in same action

But it is not proper thing as I expect there should be some thing more efficient than my suggested thing

Answer (score 0):

RoR doesn't natively use XML so some degree of conversion is required.

Having said that, XML generation is very simple in RoR applications. There are several ways of doing this, my favourite being constructing the required data as a Hash (which is native to Ruby) then the_hash.to_xml.

The XML conversion can also be defined in a model Class if you wish a consistent result:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ensure that only column1, column2, etc are output as XML
  def to_xml(options = {})
    super( options.merge( select(:column1, :column2, etc) ) )
  end

end
```

Then in your controller:

```
poster = Example.find(123)
request = Net::HTTP.new('www.example.com', 80)
request.post('/path', poster.to_xml)
```

Hopefully the above demonstrates a simple example of posting XML data to a remote host. As you mentioned, a more complicated XML can be constructed using xml.builder

HTH and good luck.